# How to make REST call to JBOSS issue tracker

Tags: java, jira

I am using the JBoss issue tracker for my project. Does anybody know how I can make a REST call to JBoss bugs (JIRA system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [JIRA REST API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) with an arbitrary REST client, e. g. [Jersey's Client API](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html).